# How to port WCF/SQL app to (SQL) Azure cloud?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, azure, azure-sql-database

I've got a local app, consisting of a windows service providing the middle/business tier for a SQL Server database (c#, .net 4, SQL Server 2008 R2)

Now I'd like to port this app to Windows Azure Cloud (both service and SQL database).
Is somewhere a document stating the differences between a local WCF service and a windows Azure Service, same for local SQL Server and SQL Azure?

Any pointers how to start porting from WCF to Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server vs SQL Azure, look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/sqlazure/default.aspx). You'll see a whitepaper link documenting the fundamental differences between SQL Server and SQL Azure. Here are additional links:

- [General Guidelines and Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx)
- [T-SQL Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336250.aspx)

For WCF in Azure, you'll need to learn about the ways to host WCF in either a WCF Service Web Role or a Worker Role. You'll also have to understand the new binding types available if accessing WCF over the Service Bus. Here are a few links to get you started:

- [Azure WCF samples and discussions](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure)
- [Patch to let WCF work properly in Azure](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB971842), due to load balancer issues